# How do I update one column based on the value of another using a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

[image: Script no Formula]

I would like to change the value in the D column based on the value of the C column if the cell in C contains "YES", using a script instead of a formula.

[Sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118vwR_bXsSrFr0dWKX_GDKzSYA86aRAawlP-CN0OCKY/edit#gid=0)

Comment: so, what exactly do you want to accomplish ? list only products that are DONE ?

Comment: JUST CHANGE THE CELL STATUS TO "DONE", IF PRODUCT HAS ARRIVED "YES"

Comment: but you already have it: =IF(C6="YES";"DONE";"")

Comment: I want a script...

Comment: @user902300 Putting a lot of extra formatting (bold, etc.) doesn't really make most posts look more appealing or make them easier to read.  Your edit did make an *overall* improvement, but much of it needed to be refined.  Please edit carefully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This function will update column D to "Done" when column "C" is updated to "Yes"

```
function onEdit() {
   var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if( r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == 'Yes')
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 1);
      nextCell.setValue("Done");
}
```

Comment: Awesome ! Its work !! Almost there. I created a column A "Satisfation". When the row = "Done", the row "Satisfation" setValue ("OK").

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118vwR_bXsSrFr0dWKX_GDKzSYA86aRAawlP-CN0OCKY/edit#gid=0

Comment: One question...Only work with formula ?

Comment: I dont want a formula cell. Just script. @Colin McCullough