# Use `setValue` to update a column based on values of two others that match their respective values in reference cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am new to Google AppScript and would really appreciate some help here.

I want to use the `setValue` along with the `for loop` and `if statement` in Google App Script to scan multiple columns in Google Sheets and set the value of data in `column F` based on the results of other columns using reference cells `B2`, `B3`.

So, if values in `column D` are equal to cell `B2` and values `in column E` are equal to cell `B3`, change the value of each row in `column F` matching that criteria from `Pending` to `Ordered`

I have attached a picture showing the desired result.

[image]

Comment: Welcome. A few things: 1) Sounds like you have a clear understanding of the process. Have you had a go at writing any code (anything at all) to do this. 2) How often/when/what trigger will drive this script? 3) You've specifically asked for a script; what if the same thing can be done by a function? have you considered that alternative? 4) Your demo data is only 5 rows, how many rows of data in your live data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update one column based on the value of another using a script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/how-do-i-update-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-using-a-script)

Comment: Thanks. 1) I have written some code, so far i'm able to change the values of a column to x using setValue but obviously it needs to meet the criteria of the reference cells first. 2) I was thinking of having it run by adding it to a custom menu. 3) Sorry I don't mean script I mean function. 4) The data will be growing so the amount of rows will change as it grows. I believe the link that you provided changes a value in a column based on a value in another column not based on a value in B2. Also another difference is there are two conditions to meet not one.

Comment: FYI - refer [Adding clause of and/or to if statement in google docs script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15855762/1330560). A good, short summary from @Sergeinsas and 'user34612' for the codes for && (and ) and || (or), as well as the conditional test of 'equal to' and 'not equal to'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see at least two alternatives to update the Order Status.

**1- Function**
`=if(and(D3=$B$2,E3=$B$3),"Ordered","Pending")`
Insert this in Cell F3, and copy down the required number of rows. This will update the Order Status dynamically.

The function is based on the conventional `if` function but the logical expression is described by an `and` with two arms.

- The first arm is whether the value of cell D3 equals the value in cell $B$2. Note that cell B2 is expressed as an absolute; no matter how many rows there may be in column D, the row value will always be compared to the value in cell B2.
- The second arm is whether the value of cell E3 equals the value in cell $B$3. Again, cell B3 is expressed as an absolute; the row value in Column E will always be compared to the value in cell B3.

**2 - Script**
The following script `so13343001` is executed by a custom menu opened by `onOpen`.

As suggested by the OP, the script uses a `for` loop and an `if` statement.

The `if` statement has two arms (just like the function) - it tests whether both the "requests" and "Supplier" values are equal to the Reference values.

The update of the order status avoids creating a `setValue` method for every row; this would be acceptable, but if there are a lot of rows, it could slow down the script. Instead, the specific cell value in the "data" array is updated, and the last statement is to `setValue(data)' to the datarange.

---

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Update-Order-Status')
      .addItem('Update Status', 'so13343001')
      .addToUi();
}

function so13343001() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "Sheet1_script";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  var LR = sheet.getLastRow();
  var Columns = 4;
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  //Logger.log(range.getA1Notation());
  var data = range.getValues();
  //Logger.log(data);

  var refReqStatus = data[1][1];
  var refSupplier = data[2][1];
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Reference Data: Request Status:"+refReqStatus+", Supplier: "+refSupplier)

  for (var i=0;i<LR-1;i++){
    var requests = data[i+1][3];
    var supplier = data[i+1][4];
    var orderstatus = data[i+1][5];
    var item = data[i+1][6];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: i="+i+", Requests: "+requests+", Supplier: "+supplier+", Order Status: "+orderstatus+", Item: "+item);

    // update the status to Ordered
    if (requests == refReqStatus && supplier == refSupplier){
      // requests and supplier match the reference data
      data[i+1][5] = "Ordered";
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: Updated status for row#"+(+i+1))
    }  
  }
  range.setValues(data);
}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you for taking time to provide these two answers. Now that I see the code and along with the logs it makes a lot more sense. Once I get more reputation I will give you an up vote. Thanks again!

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, you can accept it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)