# Script setValue in column based on the values of two columns with a case/switch and for-loop

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Sheets document in which I calculate profits based on two columns: Price and payment method. I'd like help with a script that checks the values of said columns in each row, and based on those two columns sets a certain value in another column (net profit).

So: If row 2 column E (price) = €47,00 && column H (payment method) = "iDEAL" then set the value in column K (net profit) of row 2 to €42,98.

My table:

[image: Example of my table]

---

**Text version of sample data**

| Date | Time | Order_nr | Product | Price | Vat | Email | Payment method | Couponcode | Couponamount | Net profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/12/2020 | 01:02:03 | order_wc_order_nr_2 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 14/12/2020 | 02:05:04 | order_wc_order_nr_3 | Awesome Product | $0.00 | 0 | customer@email.com |  |  | 43.12 |  |
| 16/12/2020 | 03:10:05 | order_wc_order_nr_4 | Awesome Product | $28.20 | 2.33 | customer@email.com | Bancontact |  | 17.25 |  |
| 17/12/2020 | 04:15:06 | order_wc_order_nr_5 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 05:20:07 | order_wc_order_nr_6 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 06:25:08 | order_wc_order_nr_7 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 07:30:09 | order_wc_order_nr_8 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 08:35:10 | order_wc_order_nr_9 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 09:40:11 | order_wc_order_nr_10 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | PayPal |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 10:45:12 | order_wc_order_nr_11 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 11:50:13 | order_wc_order_nr_12 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 12:55:14 | order_wc_order_nr_13 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |
| 23/12/2020 | 14:00:15 | order_wc_order_nr_14 | Awesome Product | $47.00 | 3.88 | customer@email.com | IDEAL |  |  |  |

---

This table has 3 different price values: €47, €37,9 and €28,20.
We offer four different payment methods: "iDEAL", "PayPal", "Bancontact" and "Creditcard".

For each combination of price value and payment method, there is a different net profit.

Net profit values:
[image]

---

**Table2 data as text**

| $47.00 | Net Profit |
| --- | --- |
| IDEAL | $42.89 |
| PayPal | $41.09 |
| CreditCard | $42.25 |
| BanConnect | $42.81 |
|  |  |
| $37.60 | Net Profit |
| IDEAL | $34.27 |
| PayPal | $32.47 |
| CreditCard | $33.63 |
| BanConnect | $34.19 |
|  |  |
| $28.20 | Net Profit |
| IDEAL | $25.64 |
| PayPal | $23.84 |
| CreditCard | $25.00 |
| BanConnect | $25.56 |

---

I tried to edit the following script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheetActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("mySheetID");
  var s = sheetActive.getSheetByName("mySheetName");
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
      if( r.getColumn() == 7 && r.getValue() == 47)
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 2);
      nextCell.setValue(42.89);
}
```

Based on the script in this link: [How do I update one column based on the value of another using a script?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/117908/how-do-i-update-one-column-based-on-the-value-of-another-using-a-script)

But I didn't get it to work and it also doesn't take the values of two columns into account.

I also found the following script: [Use `setValue` to update a column based on values of two others that match their respective values in reference cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/133430/use-setvalue-to-update-a-column-based-on-values-of-two-others-that-match-their)

But I haven't been able to find out how to edit the script to fit my needs.

I have minimal experience with scripting and programming but I think I need a for-loop that iterates through my rows in combination with a case/switch based on two column values.

Please help me out and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When the "Payment method" is updated on Table1, you want to lookup the net profit on Table2 based on the combination of the Table 1 Price and Payment method. Then you want to update the "Net profit" value on Table 1.

**Layout of Table 2**

The design of Table 2 is inefficient and impossible to normalise. This solution redesigns the Table 2 as shown in this image.

[image: Revised Table2]

---

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // define the sheets
  var nametable1 = "Table1";
  var nametable2 = "Table2";
  var table1 = ss.getSheetByName(nametable1);
  var table2 = ss.getSheetByName(nametable2);
  
  // variables to watch
  var watchsheet = nametable1; // sheet
  var watchcol = 8; // trigger columncolumn H-Payment method
  var pricecol = 5;   // column for price
  var npcol = 10; // net profit column: Column K (zero-based)
  var headerrows=1;   // number of header rows
  var table1spcol = 4; // var table1 sell prices are in Column E zero-based
  var table2sprow=2; // table 2 sell porices are on row 2
  
  // editted parameters - index-based, not zero-based
  var edittedcol = e.range.getColumn();
  var edittedrow = e.range.getRow();
  var edittedsheet = e.source.getSheetName();
  var edittedvalue = e.value;
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Edited details: column = "+edittedcol+", row =  "+edittedrow+", sheet = "+edittedsheet+", value = "+edittedvalue);
  
  // test sheet, column and row
  if(edittedsheet == nametable1 && edittedcol == watchcol && edittedrow >1){
    // there was a change on table 1 in Column H below row 1
    
    var table1values = table1.getDataRange().getValues(); // get the data for table1
    var table2values = table2.getDataRange().getValues(); // get the data for table2
    var sp = table1values[edittedrow][table1spcol];  // Table1 sell price
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the sell price is "+sp);
    
    // get the column of selli prices from Table 2
    var sellprices = table2values.map(function(e){return e[0];});//[[e],[e],[e]]=>[e,e,e]

    // lookup table1 sp on table2 
    // result is index number or -1 if not found.
    var result = sellprices.indexOf(sp);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the index number for the sell price is "+result)
    
    // lookup paymentmethoid from table 1 on table2 
    // result is index number or -1 if not found.
    var methodidx = table2values[0].indexOf(edittedvalue);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the index number for the payment type is  "+methodidx);
    
    // get the net profit from Table 2
    var netp = table2values[result][methodidx];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the net profit is "+netp);
    
    // update the net profit on Table1       
    table1.getRange(edittedrow,npcol+1).setValue(netp);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
  }
  
  return;
}
```

---

**Processing Logic**

The following may help you understand the aspects of the script that fit your needs.

- Table2

  - As mentioned this is simply a very poor layout for a database (which is how we are using Sheets). The new design brings all the data into a single table that can be searched efficiently.
- `onEdit(e)`

  - `onEdit` is a special script that is automatically triggered when a user edits a cell. It is one of a group known as a [Simple Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). There are also [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) that you should learn about.
  - the "e" argument refers to [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events); these are specific values and parameters that the system returns relating to the trigger. In the case of `onEdit`, this link described the [event objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit).
- `if(edittedsheet == nametable1 && edittedcol == watchcol && edittedrow >1){`

  - The script needs to ensure that the edit is on Table1, in Column H, and in a row below the header(s).
  - the three conditions are joined by `&&` which means "AND. FYI, `||` means "OR" but that doesn't apply here.
- `getValues()`

  - note that the script gets ALL the data for Table1 and Table2.
  - values in specific rows and columns can be obtained by applying the various row and column parameters that have already been identified.
- `indexOf`

  - [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is a Javascript method that searches for a value in an array.
- Table 2 - Search Selling prices.

  - `var sellprices = table2values.map(function(e){return e[0];});`
  - we need to search the column 1 of Table2. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) lets you do this by returning just the first column of the 2D Array.
- Table 2 - Search Payment Methods

  - `var methodidx = table2values[0].indexOf(edittedvalue);`
  - this enables the script to search the first row of the 2D array.